# Unity to blender Pivot points

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, maya

I am having issues exporting FBX files from unity, to blender that were previously made in Maya. When I edit the models, and replace the old FBX, the pivot points seem wrong. I am pretty sure blender doesn't import the proper pivot points to begin with. How would I go about fixing this?

I feel like I have tried just about every import/export setting, and even tested it out in maya. Maya seems to have the correct pivot points.